# Python : list of int to a function waiting for int

Tags: python, list, function, integer

I have a function f(a,b,c) waiting for 3 int. I have a list t = list(1,2,3) that i want to input to f : f(t). But it doesn't work. What is the easiest way to do it.

EDIT :  t = list('1','2','3')

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to unpack the values present in list t.

```
 f(*t)
```

Example:

```
>>> def f(a,b,c):
        print(a,b,c)

>>> t = [1,2,3]
>>> f(*t)
1 2 3
```

**OR**

```
>>> def f(a,b,c):
        print(a,b,c)


>>> t = ['1','2','3']
>>> f(*map(int,t))
1 2 3
```

Comment: What if a,b,c are strings and i want to change them in the same time to integers ?

Comment: Will the code break if the list has only 2 items (and `c` doesn't have a default value)? Just curious.

Comment: yep, because the defined function needs exactly three parameters. You could set the default value of c like `def f(a,b,c=0):`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the values as follows:

```
f(t[0], t[1], t[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function like this:

```
f(t[0],t[1],t[2])
```

Cheers!